# DolphinDB: how to obtain the records in Table T1 but not in Table T2?

Tags: mysql, select, dolphindb

Here is the illustration what I am trying to do:
[image]

In details, suppose I have two tables T1 and T2, I’d like to retrieve records exits only in T1 but not in T2.  I tried the follow SQL query just like in MySQL, it seems not working. Can anyone give me some tips?

```
T1 = table(1 2 3 3 as id, 7.8 4.6 5.1 0.1 as value)
T2 = table(5 3 1 as id,  300 500 800 as qty)
>select * from T1 where id NOT IN (select id from T2);
Syntax Error: [line #1] Two objects in an expression must be connected by an operator. Object 1: id  Object 2: NOT
```

Comment: This is a venn-diagram representative of your 'data'.  Please clarify what conditions does the shaded area mean wrt your table columns/data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left inner join:

```
T1 = table(1 2 3 3 as id, 7.8 4.6 5.1 0.1 as value)
T2 = table(5 3 1 as id,  300 500 800 as qty)
select id, value, qty from lj(T1, T2, `id) where T2.id = NULL
```

---

```
t1 = table(2021.01.01..2021.01.30 as date, take(`A`B`C`D`F`G`F, 30) as code)
t2 = table(2021.01.15..2021.02.28 as date, take(`A`B`C`D`F`G`F, 45) as code)

// method one
timer select date, code from lj(t1, t2, `date`code) where isNull(t2.date) and isNull(t2.code)

// method two
t = select date,code from ej(t1,t2,`date`code)
myDict = dict(t.date, t.code)
select * from t1 where conditionalFilter(code, date, myDict) == true
```